# Flag as Background Image for Google Web Translator Select Box

Tags: google-translate

I need to display the corresponding flag as the background image for the Google Web Translator Widget.

The code provided was:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages:'ar,de,en,es,fa,fr,it,zh-CN', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element'); }
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

How can i implement it?